# « Jalon », sens figuré (celui de « milestone »), est-il courant ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

Dans un article  anglais sur l'histoire de la mécanique j'ai vu :

> Milestones in the history of mechanics.

Je traduis cette phrase par

> Jalons dans l'histoire de la mécanique.

Peut-on employer jalon dans ce contexte (sens figuré : étapes importantes/principales) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, bien sûr. Il n'y a aucun problème à utiliser l'expression ***jalons dans l'histoire de la mécanique*** pour désigner des événements marquants de cette science.

Au sens propre, un ***milestone***, est une borne kilométrique (à la conversion d'unités près), et un **jalon**, c'est un piquet planté pour marquer quelque chose. Il n'y a donc pas de différence majeure pour le sens propre et il en va de même pour le sens figuré attendu ici (étape importante).

- **Jalon** [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jalon): *Ce qui sert à situer, à diriger (quelqu'un ou quelque chose); début, amorce d'une entreprise quelconque. Synon. étape, marque, (point de) repère.*
- ***Milestone*** [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/milestone): *An important event in a person's life or career, in the history of a nation, in the life of some project, etc.*

Il existe aussi d'autres possibilités, comme ***faits marquants***, et ceux déjà proposés dans d'autres réponses comme *[événements marquants](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32569/1109)*, *[dates-clés](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32584/1109)*, *[grands jalons](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32587/1109)*.

En restant dans le domaine de la métaphore routière, on pourra aussi parler de **tournant** dans l'histoire de la mécanique pour parler d'une étape ayant fortement remis en cause les acquis antérieurs.

Answer (score 3):

Je n'hésite pas à utiliser *jalon* pour exprimer *milestone* dans le cadre d'un projet informatique, qui dure de quelques mois à quelques années.

Mais dans l'exemple de la question où la durée est beaucoup plus longue, plusieurs dizaines voire centaines d'années, j'aurais plutôt utilisé *dates-clés*.

Answer (score -2):

Il semble que le terme « jalon » ne convienne pas. Il n'est pas question dans sa définition de marque dans un développement qui serait associée avec un aspect intéressant du sujet; il s'agit seulement d'un guide dans le développement d'une recherche, ce guide étant défini par l'homme; dans le cas de « milestone » la marque est un produit d'un concours de circonstances indépendant de la volonté humaine. Il semble qu'il n'y ait pas de terme consacré; en dehors du terme proposé, **étape importante**, que l'on peut aussi appeler « **évènement important** » je peux penser seulement au termes très voisins « **évènement marquant** », et « **étape marquante** ».

COMPLÉMENT (Une paraphrase de ce qui est exposé ci-dessus avec un dévelopement plus ample en raison de la question supplémentaire de [user **Dimitris**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32568/jalon-sens-figur%c3%a9-celui-de-milestone-est-il-courant/32569?noredirect=1#comment75234_32569) auquel le complément est adressé)

Ce nouvel examen de la question apporte accessoirement une idée de plus pour une traduction de « Milestone » : **point culminant**.

C'est assez compliqué à expliquer et se fonde sur le sens du mot tel que consigné dans le dictionnaire ; « jalon » selon le dictionnaire signifie figurativement « marque » et c'est un terme appliqué à de nombreuses entités. Fondamentalement les marques sont de deux sortes, celles déterminées par l'homme ou les circonstances, qui *ne sont pas* nécessairement dans l'existence de l'entité considérée   des points où son développement prend une tournure exceptionnelle de nouveauté inédite, et il y a ensuite les marques qui sont le résultat d'un concours de circonstances dans lequel l'homme a son rôle *mais qu'il ne contrôle pas totalement, qu'il ne décide pas* et ces marques sont en contraste des points où le développement prend une tournure exceptionnelle. Selon l'entité, la sorte de marque applicable peut être de l'une des deux sortes ou bien des deux. Dans le domaine de la *recherche scientifique* on dira par exemple « Untel a jeté les jalons  du projet » ce qui signifie que cette personne a déterminé une succession d'approches, de dates approximatives auxquelles se lancer dans de nouvelles étapes, mais à l'issue de ces étapes il n'y a aucune assurance d'un succès particulier dans le domaine de recherche en vue (cette recherche peut n'aboutir à rien du tout). Si au contraire on se penche sur une entité comme *la mécanique*, le premier type de marque n'est plus vraiment pertinent : on n'a entendu et on entend parler de la loi universelle de la gravitation, qui est un point culminant dans les annales de la mécanique, non pas parce qu'un jour Newton a décidé de se pencher sur la question mais parce qu'il a réussi a dégager de l'information qu'il a travaillée un fait jusqu'alors inconnu. Le jalon, si on doit l'appeler ainsi, c'est la découverte (une marque de seconde catégorie) pas l'entreprise d'une étude. Donc pour bien rendre l'essence de  « milestone », appelé en d'autre termes « landmark », parce que dans ce domaine la considération de marques de première catégorie n'est que d'un intérêt très secondaire,  je conçois mal « jalon » comme une  traduction vraiment bonne. On remarquera qu'en anglais *on n'emploiera jamais « milestone » pour les marques de la première catégorie*. J'espère avoir éclairci mon point de vue, mais n'hésitez pas à me demander des détails, je pourrais peut être ajouter encore quelque chose de positif.

Comment: Dans la majorité des cas vous donnez des sources pour supporter votre réponse. Ici, sur quoi vous vous appuyez lorsque vous écrivez "le terme jalon ne convienne pas" ?

Comment: @Dimitris Les explications que je peux apporter semble me demander beaucoup de longueur et je les place donc en complément de ma réponse. De plus elles semblent améliorer cette réponse.